# tkinter button text color is not changing

Tags: python, tkinter

The button text color is blue on creation, once it is clicked the button text color should change to red color as per the code. But on clicking the color is not changing

```
from tkinter import Button,Tk,Frame,DISABLED,Label
def on_click(button_id):
      btn[button_id].configure(text='clicked',state=DISABLED,fg ="red")

window = Tk()
frame = Frame(window)
frame2 = Frame(window)
frame2.pack()
frame.pack()
btn=[]
lbl=Label(frame2,text="Hello there")
lbl.pack()
for i in range(0,5):
    b=Button(frame,text="hello!!", fg="blue",font='sans 8 bold',command = lambda         
       button_id=i: on_click(button_id),width = 4, relief = "groove")
    b.grid(row=i,column=0)
    btn.append(b)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: When the Button is disabled, the `fg` option no longer applies to it; you need to set `disabledforeground` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove **`state=DISABLED`** from your **`on_click`** function to make this work

```py
def on_click(button_id):
      btn[button_id].configure(text='clicked', fg ="red")
```

Comment: thanks Poojan, after removing disabled the color is changing

Comment: no problem happy to help anytime. Make sure if this resolved your issue, mark it as answered so other people come to know its solved :)